# Where does a connection manager fit in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sockets, daemon

I'm writing a rails application that acts as a proxy, thus hereby referred to as the proxy. The idea is that the user should be able to manage his servers through a web UI, that's always up and running even if his servers are down.

To accomplish this, the proxy needs to keep an open connections to the servers at all times. For this I've created a background process using [daemonz](http://rubygems.org/gems/daemonz) that accept incomming connections from servers and spawns threads that are constantly listening on the sockets.

Now I have two problems: I need to be able to send messages on these sockets from my rails controllers and I need to know which socket to use, to reach the right server. I was planning to use a `ConnectionManager` class to take care of this for me, but I don't know where such a class fits into rails structure and I don't know how to make the object and the sockets available to both processes.

That makes two questions:

1. Where does the connection manager belong?
2. How do I share the connection manager and the sockets between the processes?

If you only know the answer to the first question, please go ahead and answer. It's possible that I should create a separate post for my second question.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem like a useful thing to build in Rails/Ruby.

What might be more useful would be a Rails admin application that configured an existing load balancer/proxy like haproxy under the covers.

You could have a mapping of servers/ports/configuration in your Rails app and then project that into an haproxy config and restart the load balancer.  A great place to start would be the [haproxy-tools gem](https://github.com/wpeterson/haproxy-tools), that allows you to parse/generate an haproxy config file.

It doesn't make sense to re-write your own load balancer and Ruby/Rails is a poor technology stack even if you were going to do that.